# When I open a .txt file, the double quotes ( " )are suppressed

Tags: gvim, filetype

First, I tried on Linux: I opened a `.txt` file (or copy and past the text from a website) but the double quotes are not shown... On Linux, they are replaced by this: `~~@~~`

On Windows 10 (I use gVim on Windows too) , the double quotes ( " ) are replaced by a small black square ( ⬛ ).

How can I fix this problem, please?

On both O.S. , I use the latest stable version.

Thank you!

Comment: please show the output of `ga` on the double quote.

Comment: if you enter your `"` would it be shown? If it is, could you update your question with an example(snippet) text you paste from the website?